# Need a loop to repeat 3 times for a special condition

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have this situation: The user must enter a number for `'x'`. If the value is `>=0`, a new game is created with this coordinate. If the user enters a negative number a message will be displayed and he will have another chance, there will be three chances to enter a correct number otherwise there will be no game. I tried an `'if-statement'` for this case but it did not work well. Is there a way of doing that inside a loop?

Comment: You'll need a variable to keep track of how many more attempts the user is permitted.

Comment: what do you do so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final static int NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
boolean correctNumber = false;
int attemptNumber = 0;

while (!correctNumber)
{

    //get user input

    if (inputIsCorrect)
    {
        createANewGame();
        correctNumber = true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect answer");
        attemptNumber++;
    }

    if(!inputIsCorrect && attemptNumber == NUMBER_OF_TRIES)
    {
        System.out.println("You have reached the max number of tries");
        System.exit(0);  //or whatever you want to happen
    }

 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop be cleaner?

Comment: A for loop could be used as well, but they would essentially look the same, the only differences would be that you could remove the attemptNumber variable and instead use a break statement if the input is correct. I personally prefer the while loop in this case though as it just seems to fit better with what is trying to be accomplished. It's a matter of preference though really.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems pretty good for me. The only thing that I don't understand is this: I have to ask the user to type 'x' so I declare, if the answer is wrong he has to type again. How can I do this without changing the variable again? Because it is already defined (int x = keyboard.nextInt(); keyboard.nextLine();).

Comment: create another boolean value to check that the input is correct. and put have the user enter it inside a nested while loop. the only way to get out of that nested loop is to use valid input otherwise it'll notify the user that the input is invalid and will list all possible valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop with the following code

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    //Perform logic
}
```

This will run exactly three times. You can change the `3` to make it run more or less times.

Comment: don't you think this will loop for 4 times?

Comment: If you use x < 3 it runs 3 times and includes the 3 to show how often it will run

Comment: Thanks for catching that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

    boolean isValidInput=false;
    int counter=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;

    while(counter<3 && isValidInput==false)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
           userInput = sc.nextInt();

        if(userInput>=0)
            isValidInput=true;

        else
            System.out.println("Please Enter valid input");

        counter++;

    }
```